# How to acquire mapbox-gl-js z-buffer

Tags: webgl, mapbox-gl-js, depth-buffer

I'm developing webgl application, where I draw detailed building on top of mapbox-gl-js.

Everything goes fine except one detail, I don't know how to acquire depth buffer of every drawn frame.

In some cases my overlay is drawn over extruded by mapbox-gl-js style buildings, but it must be behind it.

[image]

I see only one possibility to do this correctly - acquire depth buffer from mapbox-gl-js and pass it in to my shader as texture and compare with my actual depth buffer values.

As in deferred rendering technique.

Any possibility to do that?

Comment: If you dig through [this library](https://github.com/greggman/virtual-webgl) you might find be able to expose the depth buffer to your code. Unfortunately there is no real way to know. For example mapbox-gl might render the map and buildings, clear the depth buffer, then render labels or other things.

Comment: @gman amazing library, I saw you added mapbox gl example yesterday, thank you for your attention. My application now is simply stack of two canvases, where image is mathematically synced, with your lib it can be more efficient at all. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off using a [Custom Layer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#customlayerinterface).